# Newbie wants to know usefulness of web service in web application

Tags: web-services

If i several different desktop softwares installed, then making web service makes sense as all desktop softwares will access the same central remote database through web service.

But what about website? Does it make any sense to use web service in website? Personally i don't see any sense in using web service for this (if i am not using any 3rd party functionality like paypal, Amazon etc. where database etc is located remotely). Why would i ever want my database to be remote from my web application?

In my college, sir has asked me to make whole website using web service. What can be the reason. Can anybody guess?Is it not senseless?

Comment: No! he didn't give any reasons :p

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to reuse any of the existing webservices to create your web application? Or are you going to expose some of your functionality in the application as web service. If your "sir" mean to reuse all of the existing services and give it a web face then it make sense.

Comment: No unfortunately i am not going to use any of existing webservices, still he wants me to use web service. Now, does it make sense?

Comment: did he mean to say, create some web services and then consume them for your web app?? If so there may be a reason that he want to reuse those services in future or he may just want you to learn how to provide and consume web services...

Comment: He asked me to make whole web application using web service means presentation should call web service and web service should call ejb. Yes, he wants me to learn web service but does it make any sense doing this way?